# jQuery slide out navigation

Tags: jquery, mobile, navigation, boolean, tablet

What am I doing wrong here. The animation slide out the navigation, but can't slide back in.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.navLink').click(function(e){
    var navCount=0;
    if (navCount==0) {
        $('.navigation').stop().animate({'marginLeft':'0px'}, 200);
        $('#waitingPage').stop().animate({'marginLeft':'230px'}, 200);
        var navCount=1;
    }else if (navCount==1){
        $('.navigation').stop().animate({'marginLeft':'-230px'}, 200);
        $('#waitingPage').stop().animate({'marginLeft':'0px'}, 200);
        var navCount=0;
    };
    });
});//END ready
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems to me that your code could be much simpler if you used .toggle()

something like this:

```
$('.navLink').toggle(function(){

    // animation code

}, function(){

    // animation code

});
```